# Adding saving and loading prices(values) from .JSON file using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, steambot

I'm currently editing and setting up SteamBot to my own use.
Here is source code for it: https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot 
I already made my own UserHandle for it but I want it to load (and save) items prices from settings_prices.json file (for now it only remembers price until I restart .exe file).

```
static int SellPricePerKey = 70; // cena klucza w scrapach np. 31 / 9 = 3.55 ref
static int BuyPricePerKey = 69; // cena klucza w scrapach np e.g. 29 / 9 = 3.33 ref
static int SellPricePerTod = 33; // cena ToD'a w scrapach np. 31 / 9 = 3.55 ref
static int BuyPricePerTod = 28; // cena ToD'a w scrapach np. 29 / 9 = 3.33 ref
```

and price change command (Via steamchat with bot) for e.g. Selling Key(in-game item)

```
else if (message.StartsWith("!sell key"))
{
// Usage: !sell newprice "e.g. sell 26"
    int NewSellPrice = 0;
    if (message.Length >= 10)
    {
        Bot.SteamFriends.SendChatMessage(OtherSID, type, "Aktualna cena sprzedazy kluczy to: " + 
            SellPricePerKeyInRefs + " ref (" 
                + SellPricePerKey + " scapow).");

        int.TryParse(message.Substring(9), out NewSellPrice);

        Bot.log.Success("Admin zmienil cene sprzedazy kluczy z " + 
            SellPricePerKeyInRefs + " ref, na " + 
            Math.Truncate(100 * (NewSellPrice / 9.0)) / 100 + 
            " ref (" + NewSellPrice + " scapow).");

        SellPricePerKey = NewSellPrice;
        double NewSellPricePerKeyInRefs = Math.Truncate(100 * (SellPricePerKey / 9.0)) / 100;
        SellPricePerKeyInRefs = NewSellPricePerKeyInRefs;
        Bot.SteamFriends.SendChatMessage(OtherSID, type, "Zmiana ceny sprzedazy kluczy na: " + 
            SellPricePerKeyInRefs + " ref (" + 
            SellPricePerKey + " scapow).");

        Bot.log.Success("Pomyslnie zmieniono cene sprzedazy kluczy.");
    }
    else
    {
        Bot.SteamFriends.SendChatMessage(OtherSID, type, 
            "Potrzebuje nowej ceny w komendzie. Aktualna cena sprzedazy to: " + 
            SellPricePerKeyInRefs + " refa (" + SellPricePerKey + " scapow).");
    }
}
```

But I want it to save and load these prices from settings_prices.json file which looks like this:

```
{
"KeySell": "70"
"KeyBuy": "69"
"TodSell": "33"
"TodBuy": "28"
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to implement saving and loading these prices from and to settings-prices.json file. 
**Edit** I edited main question to be more specific what I want to do.

Comment: The example console program already uses a json file for loading the settings - why not take a look at that code?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
void Main()
{
    var my_object = new MyObject() {
          SellPricePerKey = 70, // cena klucza w scrapach np. 31 / 9 = 3.55 ref
          BuyPricePerKey = 69, // cena klucza w scrapach np e.g. 29 / 9 = 3.33 ref
          SellPricePerTod = 33,// cena ToD'a w scrapach np. 31 / 9 = 3.55 ref
          BuyPricePerTod = 28 // c
    };
    // create the JSON
    var json_my_object = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(my_object);

    // Retrun an a JObject with 4 objects
    var normal_deserialized_object = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_my_object);

    // Or deserialize object and play with inner bits
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject another_deserialized_object =
        (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_my_object);

    foreach (var pair   in another_deserialized_object)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key:[{0}] , Value:[{1}]", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class MyObject {
    public  int SellPricePerKey ;
    public  int BuyPricePerKey;
    public  int SellPricePerTod ;
    public  int BuyPricePerTod;
}
```

It'll return:

```
{"SellPricePerKey":70,"BuyPricePerKey":69,"SellPricePerTod":33,"BuyPricePerTod":28}
```

To save, dump that `JSON` into your file.
To load, read from the file into a string, and pass that string into the `JSON` deserialize, and you'll have your objects.